# Unclear task at new job/new mission

Tags: new-job, careers

I was sent to work at client site.

I spent 3 weeks doing nothing, but on the third week, my manager came to me and told me that I will take over somebody's job and I have two weeks to learn from him.

When this guy started "teaching" me, an anomaly was assigned to me by email, instead of the ticketing system.

The problem I am having right now is that the environment can't work correctly so that I could work entirely on that urgent anomaly, and the guy I am supposed to take over his job just explained stuff verbally and didn't show me much.

Also, there seems to be a conflict between what he does and what the manager wants me to do in the future. Anyway, it's just not clear and this anomaly just made things worse.

Also, something bothers me a lot, is that the manager didn't take the necessary actions to create my badge (formally notifying the client ...), and he told administrators to change a previous developers account name, instead of creating a new user for me. So now, in my session, logical names are mine, but physical one's are of the previous developer.

That being said, a new person joined us and got a brand new account.

I also don't understand why I still don't have a ticketing account nor any necessary account. I am still not included in a mailing list etc.

Are these working conditions acceptable?

Isn't it a bad idea to start with a very hard task as a first official task?

PS: The guy who is supposed to train me came to me yesterday in the morning to tell that they're relying on me and that I am observed as I am new and still on probation.

Am I in trouble?

I have a bad feeling about this new job since the summer, and I am tired of this lack of visibility and lack of organisation.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these working conditions acceptable?

Only you can answer that, unfortunately. What is acceptable to one person may not be acceptable to the next.

You would need to speak to your manager about the problem. From your post, I mostly deduce the issues are:

1. There is a difference between your expectation and reality. Whether your expectation is too ideal for the circumstances, or if reality can be improved, you will need to work it out with your manager.
2. Due to circumstances not meeting your expectation, it has led to difficulty performing your assigned tasks. You'd need to clearly explain how these obstacles are impeding your progress.

> Isn't it a bad idea to start with a very hard task as a first official
>   task?

I wouldn't answer that. Some people like challenges, some people take it easy.

> Am I in trouble?

If you are uncomfortable, you can always look elsewhere. Whether you want to do it now, or wait for a while to see if things resolve, is your decision.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, there seems to be a conflict between what he does and what the manager wants me to do in the future.

Not uncommon for their to be a disconnect between "the way things **were** done" and the way that they are to be done in the future. Depending on how significant a difference it would make to the approach for any current tasks I'd be inclined to wait until the previous guy leaves and then have a chat with the manager regarding what you've learnt during handover and if there are any differences the manager wants going forward.

> Also, something bothers me a lot, is that the manager didn't take the necessary actions to create my badge (formally notifying the client ...), and he told administrators to change a previous developers account name, instead of creating a new user for me. So now, in my session, logical names are mine, but physical one's are of the previous developer.

It's not *great* but it's not unheard of - particularly if the previous dev's account has substantial custom setup/permissions. This is likely just a small timesaver by taking a shortcut. Not something I'd do personally but hardly something to get upset about, let along something that should "bother you a lot"

> I also don't understand why I still don't have a ticketing account nor any necessary account. I am still not included in a mailing list etc.

This would chime with the sysadmins or manger being busy/lazy as discussed above - have you tried following up with them/the manager to see when they are going to get done?

> Isn't it a bad idea to start with a very hard task as a first official task?

Not always no, given you've currently got access to someone who can train you on this environment and setup it's much better to tackle something like that **now** when you've got the support.

> PS: The guy who is supposed to train me came to me yesterday in the morning to tell that they're relying on me and that I am observed as I am new and still on probation.

You aren't in trouble.. *yet*. But the above sounds very much like a gentle nudge that you need to up your game soon or you will be!

> I have a bad feeling about this new job since the summer

Honestly I think this is the bigger problem - having seen a few of your previous questions I think you started out with unrealistic expectations of the amount of hand-holding you were going to get.

You mention having been sent to work on-site at a client's and other details from your previous posts have given me the impression that you are working in a consultancy/contracting type situation and in the nicest possible way people in those sorts of roles are largely expected to be proactive and able to "hit the ground running" so to speak.

I realise that you had a bad experience at your previous job but you seem to be jumping at *everything* - you don't get a project - you panic, you get an easy task - you panic, you get a hard task - you panic, you don't get an account set up - you panic.

All this panicking is taking up valuable mental energy and time - focus instead on just doing the best job you can. Otherwise you'll dither around not getting anything done and end up creating the very situation you fear.

Comment: My boss's boss came to me today, and he asked me how are things going. In my mind, I thought he was going criticize me and warn me. At the opposite, he wanted to know if I was comfortable, maybe because he heard that I was not well received, and that I had been ignored for weeks. Then he called the manager and we discussed, and he told him "did you introduce him to this and that bla bla bla". And then the boss's boss told me: "do you know what's your weakness? You're very kind". "Do dare and ask". Now I feel my presence is a problem for the project manager.

Comment: I'll leave very soon. I can't work under such messy conditions.

Comment: I was asked to write a report at the end of my third month, and my between the lines, I tried to communicate the fact my staffing is a maze.